# How to replace src of images in list using javascript (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, stack-overflow

I would like to replace **thumbs** to **large** in following example using js

**FROM:**

```
<ul id="slide">
<li><img src="pathtoimg/thumbs/imagename.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="pathtoimg/thumbs/imagename2.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

**To :**

```
<ul id="slide">
<li><img src="pathtoimg/large/imagename.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="pathtoimg/large/imagename2.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

To achieve it I used following js code

```
 $(window).load(function(){
 var images = $("#slide li img");
 for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
var img = images[i];
var src = img.src.replace("thumbs","large");
img.src = src;
}
  });
```

The above code works fine in modern browsers but internet Explorer 7 & 8  returns **stack overflow at line : 0** error. Is there any other way to replace the src of img in list without getting above error on ie?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#slide > li > img").each(function(){ 
        var t = $(this);
        var src = t.attr('src');
        if(!src || typeof(src)!=='string') return;
        t.attr('src',src.replace('/thumbs/','/large/'));
    }); 

});
```

Comment: I would suggest `$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#slide > li > img").each(function(){
  var b=$(this),a=b.attr("src");
  a&&"string"===typeof a&&b.attr("src",a.replace("/thumbs/","/large/"))
 })
});`

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I tried using your code on document.ready but it is still return stack overflow error in ie.

Comment: @DavidBélanger I tried using your code too.. It still shows me Stackoverflow error ...

Comment: @KuldeepDaftary Try this update: `$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#slide > li > img").each(function(){
  var b=$(this),a=b.attr("src");
  a&&"string"===typeof a&&b.attr("src",a.replace(/thumbs/g,"large"))
 })
});`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(window).load(function(){
$("#slide li img").each(function(){
$(this).attr("src",$(this).attr("src").replace("thumbs","large"));
});
});
```